# my code is not working for program to print all prime numbers between 2 numbers

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void prime(int num1,int num2)
{
 for(int i=num1;i<=num2;i++)
 {
     if(num2%i==0)
     {
        continue;
     }
     cout<<i;
 }   
}
int main()
{
    int a,b;
    cin>>a,b;
    prime(a,b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: What the `prime` function actually does for all numbers in the range is to check, if the number divides `num2` and if it doesn't, output it; also it doesn't separate the numbers, so `prime(1, 7)` outputs `23456`

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, to input 2 numbers, it should be `cin >> a >> b`. Secondly, an actual prime check function should be written, as the `if(num2%i==0)` condition really doesn't do anything to check for primes.

Full code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

bool isPrime(int x)
{
    if (x <= 1) {return false;}
    for (int i = 2; i*i <= x; i++)
    {
        if (x%i==0) {return false;}
    }
    return true;
}

void prime(int num1,int num2)
{
    for(int i=num1;i<=num2;i++)
    {
        if (isPrime(i)) {cout << i << " ";}
    }
}
int main()
{
    int a,b;
    cin>>a>>b;
    prime(a,b);
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
10 100
11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to write an isPrime function and each iterate from num1 to num2 check if the number is prime, if it is print it, for example this is an isPrime simple function:

```
bool isPrime(int num){
    if(num == 0 || num == 1) {
        return false;
    }
    bool flag=true;
    for(int i = 2; i <= num / 2; i++) {
       if(num % i == 0) {
          flag = false;
          break;
       }
    }
    return flag;
}
```

Now change to your for loop this:

```
for(int i=num1;i<=num2;i++)
 {
     if(isPrime(i))
     {
        cout<<i;
     }
 }
```

Now it's should print all the prime numbers from num1 to num2

Comment: `isPrime` yields an incorrect result for input `1`. Furthermore `i <= num / 2` seems like an rather arbitrary choice of condition here. The condition I'd use is `i * i <= num` (effectively `i <= sqrt(num)`, since if there is a divisor > sqrt(num) there's also one < sqrt(num).

Comment: Your'e right, I just taken this example code from the internet, fixed it.